# Lucas Lehmer C implementation up to M31 without BIGINT

Tags: c

I started learning C yesterday and I've literally just learned the basic data types (char, int, float), while loops, operators and printing.

Before I learn anything more, I wanted to set myself a mathematical challenge as the above should be enough to do elementary arithmetic. These are the constraints I'm working within - I'm well aware there are other ways to do the problem, like I could create an array to store all of the values of the Lucas Lehmer sequence, or I could use BIGINT etc. But I'm trying to use just what I've learned so far.

It just so happens that the largest possible INT value in C is 2^31-1, which is also a Mersenne Prime, M31. So I'd like to write a function which tests all candidate Mersennes up to M31.

This was my initial stab at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int p = 3;
    while (p < 32) {
        int e = 0;
        int Mp = 1;
        while (e < p) {
            Mp *= 2;
            ++e;
        }
        Mp -= 1;
        printf("Testing p=%d: %d\n", p, Mp);
        int i = 0;
        int Si = 4;
        while (i < (p - 2))
        {
            Si = (Si * Si - 2) % Mp;
            ++i;
        }
        if (Si == 0) {
            printf("2^%d is prime: %d\n", p, Mp);
        }
        ++p;
        ++p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This worked up to p = 13, at which point we get a problem in the generation of the Si numbers, in particular the squaring, which wraps round beyond the limit for a signed INT.

In order to handle the squaring in a way that doesn't involve getting a number bigger than 2^31-1 I turned multiplication into repeated addition:

```
int main() {
    int p = 3;
    while (p < 32) {
        int e = 0;
        int Mp = 1;
        while (e < p) {
            Mp *= 2;
            ++e;
        }
        Mp -= 1;
        int i = 0;
        int Si = 4;
        while (i < (p - 2))
        {
            int newSi;
            newSi = 0;
            int multiplications = 0;
            while (multiplications < Si) {
                newSi = (newSi + Si) % Mp;
                ++multiplications;
            }
            Si = newSi - 2;
            ++i;
        }
        if (Si == 0) {
            printf("2^%d is prime: %d\n", p, Mp);
        }
        ++p;
        ++p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this had a huge effect on the time complexity of the function. It also only detected up to 2^19-1 as prime. Switching all values to unsigned instead of int makes the algorithm work up to 2^31 - 1, as below, but I'm trying to avoid doing so as I'd really like to do this within the bounds of a signed integer, just to see if it's possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned p = 3;
    while (p < 32) {
        unsigned e = 0;
        unsigned Mp = 1;
        while (e < p) {
            Mp *= 2;
            ++e;
        }
        Mp -= 1;
        unsigned i = 0;
        unsigned Si = 4;
        while (i < (p - 2))
        {
            unsigned newSi;
            newSi = 0;
            unsigned multiplications = 0;
            while (multiplications < Si) {
                newSi = (newSi + Si) % Mp;
                ++multiplications;
            }
            Si = newSi - 2;
            ++i;
        }
        if (Si == 0) {
            printf("2^%d is prime: %d\n", p, Mp);
        }
        ++p;
        ++p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this has had a huge effect on the time complexity of the function.

Can anyone advise if there's an efficient way to run this function with only the functionality I've learned to date? I'm very particular about this constraint on the functionality I can use - I could easily just follow the next few lessons and learn other features of C, but the challenge here is to do so **using these elementary skills only**. I have found other questions on StackOverflow relating to an implementation of LL testing, but none that ask about an efficient algorithm that just uses math operators, int, while and printf.

Comment: Re “Can anyone advise if there's an efficient way to run this function with only the functionality I've learned to date?”: In elementary school, you were taught methods for doing arithmetic on multiple-digit numbers using single-digit operations. Use those same methods using digits of base 2^16 or 2^8 instead of base 10.

Comment: Could you be a bit less cryptic please? I'm a high school math teacher so I no doubt know what you're referring to but can't work out what you mean!

Comment: The statement "the largest possible INT value in C is 2^31-1" is not guaranteed by C.  It will be true in some environments and false in others.

Comment: Not towards an answer, but `"2^%d is prime: %d\n"` cannot match what you want to print there. I think a `"-1"` is missing somewhere.

Comment: If you want to perform extended precision arithmetic, there are two obvious approaches:  (1) Use a larger integer size to perform the multiplications, e.g. `long long int`, or (2) do it manually by chopping up your two integers into four half-integers, then perform four half-integer multiplications (producing full integer partial results).  For example, if you have 32-bit integers (and you know your values are positive), you can use `(x & 0xffff)` and `((x >> 16) & 0xffff)` to get the low- and high-order halves.

Comment: How do you multiply 789 by 456 using paper and pencil?

Comment: @Yunnosch - Good spot, thank you!

Comment: The easiest approach is to just use a wider type: https://godbolt.org/z/Yjxsf6nnP . Other than that, there exist libraries like [gmp](https://gmplib.org/).